# help with error modifier cannot be applied on multi-user data

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

Error: modifier cannot be applied on multi-user data
on the stage I have objects copied via Alt + D on them I cannot apply modifiers, although I could before
when trying to create a new object of any shape or taking another object that was not duplicated, I also cannot apply the modifier ... what wrang whis Blender?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271147/how-to-fix-modifier-is-disabled-skipping-apply-when-applying-subdivision

Comment: i forgot i set it to 0...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, thank you