Why is Blender Saying Modifier disabled, Skipping Apply, and How to Fix It?
So one day i launch blender to finish the character by applying the subdivision modifier, and it wouldn't work or show on the model 



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271147/how-to-fix-modifier-is-disabled-skipping-apply-when-applying-subdivision
